# Web scraping into a dataframe. Getting error when adding a column

Tags: python, pandas, calculated-columns

My error: "list indices must be integers or slices, not list"

I know that there are seemingly endless amounts of posts related to that error, but I've searched and can't figure it out. If there is a solution that I missed and will help me, please let me know.

Anyways...

I'm using pandas to web scrape stock information into a dataframe, then add two calculated columns to the end:

1. to calculate the price
2. another unrelated calc

The issues I'm seeing is when I try to add the first calculated column (the last bit of code):

```
# Dependencies
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'http://www.dividend.com/dividend-stocks/preferred-dividend-stocks.php#stocks&sort_name=Symbol&sort_order=ASC&page=1'
tables = pd.read_html(url)
tables

type(tables)
type(tables[0])
tables[0].head()

tables['Perp Value'] = (1/(tables['Dividend Yield']/100))*tables['Annual Dividend']
tables[0].head()
```

When I try to add the column 'Perp Value' I get the error. What do I need to add to be able to do my calc?

For reference, the unformatted data looks like:

> \nDividend Yield\n \nCurrent Price\n \nAnnual Dividend\n  \n52-Week High\n  \
>    0               8.04%            $25.65               $2.06             25.98
>    1               7.61%            $25.47               $1.94             25.95
>    2               6.66%            $25.82               $1.72             28.80
>    3               7.47%            $25.95               $1.94             26.87
>    4               5.78%            $25.72               $1.49             28.99
>    5               8.06%            $26.20               $2.11             26.00
>    6               7.72%            $23.87               $1.84              0.00
>    7               7.75%            $23.80               $1.84              0.00
>    8               7.80%            $24.05               $1.88              0.00
>    9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Try this:

Find column names:

```
list(tables[0])

['\nStock Symbol\n',
'\nCompany Name\n',
'\nDividend Yield\n',
'\nCurrent Price\n',
'\nAnnual Dividend\n',
'\n52-Week High\n',
'\n52-Week Low\n']
```

Clean data and convert to numeric:

```
a = tables[0][list(tables[0])[4]]
a = a.replace('[\$,]', '', regex=True).astype(float)
b = tables[0][list(tables[0])[2]]
b = b.replace('[\%,]', '', regex=True).astype(float)
```

Output:

```
(1/a/100)*b

0     0.039029
1     0.039227
2     0.038721
3     0.038505
4     0.038792
5     0.038199
6     0.041957
7     0.042120
8     0.041489
9     0.041649
10    0.038594
11    0.039053
12    0.038795
13    0.037853
14    0.037546
15    0.039100
16    0.039320
17    0.039898
18    0.038431
19    0.040290
dtype: float64
```

Assign:

```
tables[0]["Perp Value"] = (1/a/100)*b
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped...but how do I get it back into a dataframe from the list?